# Current status of HBase Thrift API

Tags: php, api, hbase, thrift

Does anyone knows what is the current status of HBase Thrift API ?

I'm especially interested in writing PHP to work with HBase over this API, first of all this API lacks support for few important features like for example regexp scanning (there's a lot more).

Where can I find information about current progress on implementing those features?
[Hbase/ThfirtApi](http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/Hbase/ThriftApi) wiki seems to be a little outdated, has whole HBase+Thrift (+PHP) idea been abandoned ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A great synopsis of and example of PHP using THRIFT at [Introduction to REST, Thrift and Avro](http://ofps.oreilly.com/titles/9781449396107/clients.html) which is part of the excellent Online version of [HBase: The Definitive Guide](http://ofps.oreilly.com/titles/9781449396107/) by Lars Geroge

The basic [HBase Thrift](http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/Hbase/ThriftApi) [API](http://hbase.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/thrift/package-summary.html) is stable, but there is work going on for a Thrift2 for HBase. It looks like there is a strong effort so that current clients will continue to operated and new clients can use the new Thrift2 api when it comes out. Experimental patches are available that can be applied to HBase trunk if you really want to. See [HBASE-1744 Thrift server to match the new java api.](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HBASE-1744) which has the patches and discussion of the reasoning and status.

IMHO  don't use Thrift2 now as it seems to be under active development (unless you want to help out with its development). It sounds like they are going to maintain the current Thrift api for a while.

Answer (score 0):

Update: In the meantime, the new API is the preferred one, and the old API is going to be deprecated. More information [can be found here](http://www.cloudera.com/content/cloudera-content/cloudera-docs/CDH5/latest/CDH5-Installation-Guide/cdh5ig_hbase_upgrade.html).